# Несколько элементарных вопросов по HTML

Tags: html

Делаю отчёт в чистом html и у меня возникли небольшие трудности.

1)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот к примеру первая проблема, очень большие отступы margin по всем фронтам, пытался фиксить таким кодом (который ничего не делает) :

```
 <h6 style="width: 1px; height: 1px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">
```

Код таблицы:

```
<table width="100%" height="10%" border-top ="solid" border ="solid" height="2>
<td rowspan="2">
<img src="Z:\12.bmp width="100" height="90" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px">
</td>
<td>
<h6  style="width: 0px; margin-right: 0px; font-size: 20px" >БОРЬКАНСКИЙ</h6>
</td>
<td style="font: bolder;">
<p> 
<h2> Испытания </h2>
<h6> нижний текст  </h6>
</p>
</td>
<tr>
<td> <p> <h6 align="center" style="border-top:solid;" > 432 </h6>
<h6 align="center"> 123) </h6> </p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

2) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и второй пример, как сделать этот интервал (от i до 123) не быдлокодом (я это делал при помощи белого текста в <.h1>)

Comment: Вставить ваш код с помощью снипета, пожалуйста, для запуска

Comment: Всё же это не чистый html, а и css тоже. По скриншоту хорошо видно, что всё растянуто соседними ячейками таблицы — вот соседние ячейки и сужайте. И не пишите два вопроса внутри одного

Comment: 2) использовать `margin`

Comment: <br> - перенос строки. Для решения первого вопроса откройте консоль разработчика в браузере и изучите этот инструмент, а затем поймете почему у вас пустое место.

Comment: кто-то пользуется еще `<br>` ??? По моему в данном случае это гомнокод ) и он чутка по лучше чем в данный момент у автора

Comment: @andreymal как их сузить? например можно сузить правую ячейку (3-ию из 3), если увеличить width то он уходит из рамки А4 листа...

Comment: @ElemStack без рабочего примера кода ответить вряд ли получится. Вы даже умолчали, что у вас вообще таблица, и мне пришлось по скриншоту угадывать — лучше предоставьте [mcve] чтобы не гадать

Comment: @andreymal, извиняюсь, не подумал, что это будет не понятно!
я добавил в сам вопрос код этой таблицы (идёт после "Код таблицы:")

Comment: @ElemStack исправьте хотя бы незакрытые кавычки и другие синтаксические ошибки в коде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задумку... (или исправьте в комментарии)

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #555; padding: 5px;">
      <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/03fcf3c9a86b00f85f98fa343149e740.png" >
    </td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #555; padding: 5px; vertical-align: top;">
      <span  style="font-size: 20px;" >БОРЬКАНСКИЙ</span>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2" style="border: 1px solid #555; padding: 5px; vertical-align: top; width: 100%; max-width: 900px;">
      <div style="font-size: 30px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><b>Испытания</b></div>
      <span>нижний текст</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #555; vertical-align: top;">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 60px;">432</div>
      <div>123</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Теги заглавлений созданы для того, чтобы быстро записать заглавление, с заранее известным размером!) Если хочется манипулировать шрифтом, размером и т.п., то их запросто может заменить span или div / p, в зависимости от ситуации.

Здесь использованы div, потому что у них по дефолту стоит `display: block; width: 100%;` — display: block заставляет элемент расположиться на новой строке, отдельно от всего что до или после него.

У вас было куча отступов из-за ненужной высоты таблицы и ширины 100%. Можно не задавая строгую ширину, дать каждому блоку таблицы получить свой размер в зависимости от его внутренностей (или ограничить max-width), а только последнему блоку выдать `width: 100%`, он уже займет всё свободное место, которое осталось уже после остальных td.

P.s. есть удобные редакторы для кода, сразу указывающие на ошибки, незакрытую кавычку и т.п. — [LiveWeave](https://liveweave.com/), [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), [Playcode](https://playcode.io/)

Comment: Спасибо, да, это то что нужно!
у меня были кавычки все закрыты, я просто когда убирал быдлокод (для поста сюда), случайно захватил парочку нужных.

Comment: Этот "чистый HTML", кстати... был придуман для того, чтобы максимально просто представить разметку страницы. А style="километровые стили" только запутывают код. Поэтому был придуман CSS - тот же стиль, только записанный в другом месте. Чтобы в каждом `td` не повторять одинаковый стиль, где-то в самом верху добавляется `<style> td { border: 1px solid #555; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; }</style>` - и всё, все td на странице будут иметь такой стиль. ( если захочется поставить что-то в центре td, `style="vertical-align: middle"` )